# PowerShell to delete FieldLinks for List Content Type in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-type

Want to know how to delete the fieldlinks for the content type.

```
        Write-Host "Deleted Redundant ACL Columns from List " $list " for 
         web " $web.title

        $sitecols = @{"BU" = "BU"; "Discipline" = "Discipline";}

        $cttypes = @("Memo","Model")

        foreach ($cttype in $cttypes)
        {
            $cttypeo = $list.contenttypes[$cttype]

            $cttypeo.FieldLinks.delete($fieldbuLink.Id)
            $cttypeo.FieldLinks.delete($fielddisciplineLink.Id)
        }
```

I am trying to apply the  above code for deleting the `List Content Type` association for my `Document Library`.But somehow its not working.What I am missing here? After executing this script I am still able  to see the  list content type association  still  exists!

Answer (score 2):

You should update your content type using `$cttype.Update()` in your foreach sequense after field link deletion

Comment: I added the code for updation.But that update method gave me error it has been modified by another user.

Comment: Use a for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: Yeah, @Bunzab could be correct, because your content type collection is modified and foreach statement fails. Possibly, that's why you get error.